# QGIS Expand layer rather than zoom when reaching max zoom extent

Tags: qgis, zoom

When I zoom in to a layer in QGIS (specficially http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer ) I reach a point where going further beyond I get tiles that say "Map data not yet available"

What I would like is when I reach that max zoom, instead of polling for new tiles, it simply blows up the last available tile, even if that means gross pixellation.

I'm sure there's a simple setting somewhere on the layer, but I don't have the correct terminology (I'm sure) so searching is coming up empty.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you seek does not exist in QGIS 2.x or QGIS 3.2. It also does not exist in ArcMap 10.x.

The problem is not with QGIS but with the web map service where the latter (in its metadata) claimed to have tiles for the requested level and extent but the tiles are just "Map data not yet available".

Comment: Interesting. So they are serving blank tiles...? Seems then a setting would say "stop requesting tiles at [some arbitrary level] and just blow up the last available tile for the rest of the zoom.